# Which of these non-well founded set theories is synonymous with ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Lets add a constant $\mathcal A$ to the language of $\sf ZFC$.

Let "Foundation$_{\mathcal A}$" denote the following sentence:

$$ \forall x: \forall y \in x \exists z \in y \cap x \to \exists y \in  \mathcal A \cap x  $$

In English: all sets that have nonempty intersections with all of their elements, must have a nonempty intersection with set $\mathcal A$

Let $\sf ZFC_\mathcal A$ be $\sf ZFC$ with Foundation replaced by Foundation$_{\mathcal A}$ and the rest of axioms modified accordingly.

> What axioms $\varphi(\mathcal A)$ that when added to $\sf ZFC_{\mathcal A}$ would render the resulting theory synonymous with $\sf ZFC$?

> Is there a formula that collectively characterizes such sets? That is, it does the above and in addition if $\neg \varphi(\mathcal A)$, then the resulting theory is not synonymous with $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: $A = \emptyset$ would suffice

Comment: This is inconsistent.